# How to change spacing between icons in GNOME taskbar?

Tags: gnome, icons, taskbar

I'd like to change the spacing between the icons on the GNOME taskbar.

I don't want to change the size of the icons. I only want to change the spacing.

I have tried both GNOME Tweaks and dconf editor but have not been able to find a place to tweak this.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10.